# Where to ask question regarding online solution?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I'm not even sure this is the right place to ask this question, but here I go anyway.

I am quite confused after reading the FAQ of the different websites on the Stack Exchange network, all stating you should not ask questions regarding websites.

I wanted to ask whether anybody knew of a good place to publish "blog"-like articles which would provide a permanent public link to refer too, without the hassle of creating an entire blog for a single article.

My question will instead be: **"Where should I ask such a question?"**

Comment: Probably nowhere on the SE network is this an on-topic question.

Comment: http://squidoo.com should be okay. But not on Stack Exchange

Comment: [webapps.se] would probably be the place to ask questions about _using a particular such service_, but asking people to recommend one to you would likely be as off-topic there as anywhere else.

Comment: +1 for actually reading the FAQs

Comment: @hammar: I thought about it, but since the question is not on one and one only webapps, I guess it's not allowed

Comment: @random: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks alright though not exactly what I was looking for. Maybe, in the mean time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that they all see a ton of action, but I would recommend asking in either:

- [The WebApps chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/webapps)
- [Root-Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)
- [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) <-- while a bit more off-topic, there are plenty who frequent this room who would be glad to help.

That said, I'm not sure there *exists* a website within the Stack Exchange community where this sort of solicitation for opinion would be welcomed.

Trying to phrase it as carefully as possible, you might get traction on the [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) site, but I think you'd need to beg (and cite this discussion) to prevent the mods from closing it...

Comment: On the Tavern, Sathya advise me to check platforms such as Tumblr, Posterous or friendfeeds. Though they don't seem to fully correspond to what I am looking for, it might be a good start

Comment: Yep.  Sorry that I can't be of more help.  I only use Movable Type for blogging & that only for private blogs viewable/hosted only on my laptop <-- more of an idea organiser.

Comment: I marked this as answered though it did not solve my original problem, to thanks M. Tibbits for his help on the matter.
If it interest anyone, I went for a private post on Tumblr (I had to create an account, mind you) and shared the link. Did the trick, I suppose. Thanks again